# Modifying Authors and Utilizing Git Rebase in Collaborative Workflows

Tags: git, github, rebase

Is it feasible to modify the authorship information, including name, email, and commit content, for a specified range of commits?

This scenario arises when multiple collaborators contribute to a shared repository. Additionally, what are the benefits of employing Git rebase, and in what circumstances should this technique be utilized?

I'd like to change the all author's email on a repository history for a specific author's in multiple contributors

Comment: “Additionally, what are the benefits of employing Git rebase, ...” This is too large (encompassing) question to ask “in addition”. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The main point is to change the author's email and username for a repository, guess "git rebase" would be used effectively for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you haven't already done so, you will likely want to fix your name in git-config:

```
git config --global user.name "New Author Name"
git config --global user.email "<email@address.example>"
```

This is optional, but it will also make sure to reset the committer name, too, assuming that's what you need.

To rewrite metadata for a range of commits using a rebase, do

```
git rebase -r <some commit before all of your bad commits> \
    --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author'
```